# Google sheet complex query?

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges

Hello I need help with named range in google sheet...

> `=QUERY(Data,"SELECT C,D,E,SUM(G),L,SUM(G*M) WHERE A = '"&$A$1&"' AND E = '"&$B$1&"' GROUP BY C,D,E,L",1)`

I'd like to calculate `columnG*columnM` and than SUM this results when grouping.

This works fine before I start grouping table. I could do `columnG*columnM` get result and use another QUERY but don't like the idea of using many helpers. Is it even possible?

Comment: What is `Data` and what problems are you having with the formula you added?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a link to your project ? I make a simplified example : if you need the sum of ColumnB x ColumnC, you have to add to your data an extra column as following

```
=query({A2:C,arrayformula(B2:B*C2:C)},"select SUM(Col4) group by Col1 ")
```

and then usie ColX instead of A,B,C and the extra column D.

Comment: Nope I can not since it's a policy rule. I'm on g-suite. Thanks to give it a try, so far not working. I'll probably try to group data before so I'll take calculated data from named range.